# 24 cores and MYSQL is using 1 on INSERT

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Hi my server have 24 cores and 32GB of memory.
Am doing multiple "INSERT INTO SELECT" of 50 millions row at a time.
This takes about 15h a query but it is ticking along at 100% of only one CPU, I'am trying to get mySQL(5.5)(InnoDB) to use more of the resources.

I have read multiple threads about it, but I do not get it to work.

Most info is about adding `innodb_thread_concurrency = 0`
But I still get no results.

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /media/ssd/db
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_buffer_pool_size=26G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0

bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 1000M
max_allowed_packet  = 160M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
table_cache            = 800

query_cache_limit   = 5000M
query_cache_size    = 1600M
join_buffer_size    = 1000M


log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
```

Comment: You might have more luck on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Looks better fits in [Database Administration](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this parameters:

```
innodb_io_capacity=5000 (or even 20000 depending on your IO subsystem)
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G (for example)
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
```